# Internationalization in Java Child Classes

Tags: java, oop, localization, internationalization, extends

I have a parent class, which extends JFrame. This parent class contains menu items which are supposed to change the language on the interface.

```
public class ParentCLass extends JFrame{
//.....
locale = Locale.getDefault();
titleList = ResourceBundle.getBundle("res.TitleBundle", locale);
//....
JMenu languageMenu = new JMenu("Language");
menuBar.add(languageMenu);
JMenuItem englishItem = new JMenuItem("English");
JMenuItem germanItem = new JMenuItem("German");
languageMenu.add(englishItem);
languageMenu.add(germanItem);
//added the actionlisteners to the menu items
public void setLocale(String language){
        if (language.equals("en")) {
            locale = new Locale("en","US");
        } else
            if (language.equals("de")) {
                locale = new Locale("de","DE");
            }
        titleList = ResourceBundle.getBundle("res.TitleBundle",locale);
        refresh();
    }
}
```

The refresh() method should refresh every interface element from the UI, to fit the selected language.

Now, the problem is that I have several child classes which extend this ParentClass, and the interface may differ from child class to child class.

Can I somehow pass the refresh event from the parent class to the child class? The UI elements should be refreshed there.

Comment: The subclasses of ParentClass are free to override `refresh()` with their own implementation.  Are you asking for a way to automate the updating of a component tree from a ResourceBundle?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to force users to set UI language, whereas it is already set by an OS? In a desktop application there should be no language switchers, all you have to do is read the default Locale: ``locale = Locale.getDefault(LocaleCategory.DISPLAY);``. That solves the problem once an for all.